# Using docker and docker-compose in order to run npm install and bower install

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, bower, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker with a node image in order to run `npm install` and `bower install`.

Here is the relevant portion from my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
node:
  image: node:0.10.40
  volumes:
   - ./package.json:/package.json
   - .bowerrc:/.bowerrc
   - ./bower.json:/bower.json
   - ./build/npm.tmp/node_modules:/node_modules
   - ./build/npm.tmp/bignibou-client/src/bower_components:/bignibou-client/src/bower_components
  command: bash -c "npm install && bower install"
  ports:
   - "8888:8888"
```

Unfortunately I get the following error from node:

```
node_1          | bash: bower: command not found
bignibousite_node_1 exited with code 127
```

Indicating the command was not interpreted properly.

I have also tried using a post-script in my package.json as follows:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "/node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
  }
```

Here is my `.bowerrc`:

```
{
    "json": "bower.json", "directory": "bignibou-client/src/bower_components"
}
```

Without the bower install, the `npm install` is run OK. It is really the `bower install` that I cannot get to work.

Can anyone please help?

**edit**: the **postinstall script** above gives me this error from node:

```
node_1          | npm WARN cannot run in wd bignibou-client@0.1.0 /node_modules/bower/bin/bower install (wd=/)
```

**edit 2**: I tried the solution suggested by Alexis i.e. using an existing image but I tried to specify a local bower.json, etc. as follows:

```
docker run -it --rm \
   -v ./package.json:/package.json  \
   -v .bowerrc:/.bowerrc \
   -v ./bower.json:/bower.json  \
   -v ./build/npm.tmp/node_modules:/node_modules  \
   -v ./build/npm.tmp/bignibou-client/src/bower_components:/bignibou-client/src/bower_components \
   digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt bower install
```

I get this error though:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:224
      throw er
            ^
Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:552:19)
    at Object.fs.readSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:218:23)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:384:28)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/lib/util/rc.js:75:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at json (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/lib/util/rc.js:74:14)
    at rc (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/lib/util/rc.js:31:9)
    at Config.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/lib/Config.js:14:20)
    at Function.Config.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-config/lib/Config.js:49:19)
```

I am not sure why I get this and how to sort it out.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should install bower globally in your image

Create this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:0.10.40
RUN npm install -g bower
```

And reference it in the docker-compose.yml file

```
node:
  build: .  // <= Path to the folder containing the Dockerfile

...
```

Otherwise, there is a popular image on dockerhub [digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt](https://hub.docker.com/r/digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt/) that already provides it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like the link provided. I am not sure how to specify a local bower.json, bowerrc, etc. though... Let me edit my post.

Comment: I am not sure how to check permissions on a container that is not running. Is it possible? If so how? Anyway I tried running the container as privileged `--privileged=true` and I get the same error..

Comment: Doesn't  the error above mean that it is trying to treat a file as a directory or vice versa?

Comment: Seems possible, but I think it should be a different question then. To check the permissions, run a `bash` command in a container instead of `bower install` with the options `-it` (to run it in interactive mode). Then you will be able to check the permissions. It's very useful for debugging.

Comment: Neat command. I can see the contents of the container! However, when I do a cat of my package.json, I get this: `root@b8ffe48ca6a3:/# cat package.json/
cat: package.json/: Is a directory`

Comment: A `cat package.json ` runs OK within the directory where the docker run command is run. I see the output of the json file.

Comment: I opened another post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081856 and found a solution to the file/directory mix up.

Comment: However, I still haven't found a way to use the image to generate a `node_modules` and a `bower_components` on my local machine/host.

Comment: Ok, I see. Btw, the absolute path thing is not necessary using *compose*, but you have to do it for all your volumes using `docker run`.