# Docker volume command line option mistaking files for directories

Tags: docker

I have the following command:

```
docker run --privileged=true -it --rm \
   -w /usr/src/app \
   -v ./package.json:/usr/src/app/package.json  \
   -v .bowerrc:/usr/src/app/.bowerrc \
   -v ./bower.json:/usr/src/app/bower.json  \
   -v ./build/npm.tmp/node_modules:/usr/src/app/build/npm.tmp/node_modules  \
   -v ./build/npm.tmp/bignibou-client/src/bower_components:/usr/src/app/build/npm.tmp/bignibou-client/src/bower_components \
   digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt bash
```

I end up with `package.json` being a **directory** in the docker container **instead of a file**.

```
root@c706711a7ad4:/usr/src/app# cat package.json/
cat: package.json/: Is a directory
```

How can I sort this problem? What am I getting wrong with the syntax?

**edit**:

Using the advice from @manojlds works fine:

Changing to  `-v $(pwd)/package.json:/usr/src/app/package.json  \`

sorts out the issue.

Comment: I think most of what you want to do is already done in the [digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt/~/dockerfile/)

Comment: @isim: I was not able to get the container you mention to generate bower_components into my local machine/host...

Comment: Any clue that could help me?

Comment: Not too sure myself... Have you tried running just `$ docker run -it --rm digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt bower` per the [usage page](https://hub.docker.com/r/digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt/)?

Comment: I have actually: `docker run -it --rm digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt bower install` yields a `bower                           ENOENT No bower.json present`

Comment: Strange. The dockerfile does this for you: `ONBUILD COPY bower.json .bowerrc* /usr/src/app/`. And what happened if you leave out `install`, and just `digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt bower`?

Comment: The dockerfile installs bower for you too: `ONBUILD RUN bower install`

Comment: If I leave out the `install` command, I get the usage prompt that one gets when forgetting the command.

Comment: I must mention that I use VirtualBox/docker-machine and Mac OS X. Could it be that the files are generated by bower on the virtual box guest?

Comment: Try usethe `onbuild` tag by doing `$ docker run <image>:onbuild`. I think your `docker run` is pulling the [latest](https://github.com/DigitallySeamless/docker-nodejs-bower-grunt/blob/master/Dockerfile) dockerfile. The one that was published on their dockerhub page is the [`0.12-onbuild`](https://github.com/DigitallySeamless/docker-nodejs-bower-grunt/blob/onbuild/Dockerfile) (latest onbuild) tag.

Comment: Hi. I tried as advised and I did see the bower dependencies being pulled up but they are nowhere to be found on the host... When I tried the command again bower does not pull anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try providing an absolute path, instead of a relative path:

```
-v /home/projects/package.json:/user/src/app/package.json
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt/~/dockerfile/) in the `digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt` repo already does most of what you're trying to do:

1. `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` - Set the workspace
2. `ONBUILD COPY package.json /usr/src/app/` - Copy the `package.json` file into the container.
3. `ONBUILD COPY bower.json .bowerrc* /usr/src/app/` - Copy the `bower.json` into the container.
4. `ONBUILD RUN bower install` - Install bower

If you are lucky, you might be able to just do `$ docker run -it --rm digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt`, (or `$ docker run -it --rm digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt bower` for bower), and it will work.